# Content restriction based on IP range

Tags: permissions

Has anyone ever heard of anything that would control content based on IP range?
I am looking to regionalize content for a site.

ie: regionalized promotions offered in a certain area are displayed based on your IP

Comment: IP address countries are an estimate at best. You should probably also provide a dropdown and let users change their country/region.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a bunch of plugins that do this: http://devot-ee.com/search/tags/tag/ip

Hope that helps!

I did some research and found that you can do exactly what you want with this plugin: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ipgeo

and this logic

```
{if "{exp:ipgeo:country}" == "United States"}US featured content{/if}
```

Cheers!